# How to select from two tables where the rows may be or may not be equal and group it if they are equal

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables of images `ojm_pages_articles_photos`, `ojm_images_optimized` but I want to select rows that are common to them and also rows that are NOT common to them. In case common rows are found, they should be grouped but in case they are not, the single rows should be selected. The problem in my code is that it only selects and group records that are found both in the two tables but i want records to also be selected when they are found only in table `ojm_pages_articles_photos` and not in the other one.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_pages_articles_photos`, 
                `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo`, 
                `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_ojm_peoples` AS `id_ojm_peoples_uploader` 
FROM    `ojm_pages_articles_photos`, 
        `ojm_images_optimized`  
WHERE `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%jpeg%'
  AND `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo`=`ojm_images_optimized`.`url_image_original`
GROUP BY    `ojm_images_optimized`.`url_image_optimized`
ORDER BY    `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_pages_articles_photos` DESC, 
            `ojm_images_optimized`.`optimized_is_smaller`='Oui'
```

I used `AND  (ojm_pages_articles_photos.url_articles_photo=ojm_images_optimized.url_image_original) GROUP BY ojm_images_optimized.url_image_optimized`

to select where the file is in both tables and group it but there sometimes where the files are only in table ojm_pages_articles_photos but not in the other.

**How to select from those two tables where the rows may be or may not be equal and group it if they are equal ?**

Comment: *they should be grouped* And how it is to look like? Show DDLs. Show data example and desured result for it. PS. Your GROUP BY is incorrect (no aggregate function used). And combination of GROUP BY and DISTINCT is strange in close ti all cases.

Comment: They are grouped but it does not display the file that is not in two tables. It only display those that are in the two tables

Comment: You use INNER JOIN in cartesian form. It cannot show record which is absent in one of tables.

Answer (score 0):

FULL JOIN is not implemented in MySQL.

Possible realization (model):

```
SELECT filename,
       CASE SUM(table_from) WHEN 1 THEN 'In first table'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'In second table'
                            ELSE        'In both tables'
                            END AS where_it_is
FROM ( SELECT filename, 1 AS table_from
       FROM table1
       UNION DISTINCT
       SELECT filename, 2
       FROM table2 ) AS combined_data_array
GROUP BY filename
```

If the field in question is unique in each separate table then use UNION ALL instead of UNION DISTINCT.